# select from three tables in one query gives multiplied result

Tags: python, sqlite

I try to select from three tables in one query.
these three sql tables I select has 93 lines per table

```
import sqlite3
```

database = sqlite3.connect('F.tsj')
cursor = database.cursor()
cursor.execute("select Name, C1, C2, C3, NumofEpochs, HDop, VDop, NumOfGpsSats, SecondsFrom1970 from tblSoPoints, tblCrdGnssRaw, tblCrdRawMeas where keySoPoint and keyCrdGnssRaw = keyCrdRawMeas")
results = cursor.fetchall()

and then I try:

```
for line in enumerate(results):
    print line
```

what gives me 8648 lines and this is 93 * 93 or 92**2.
When I select from only two tables in one query, everything is ok, I get 93 lines.
How can I select from three tables in one query and get right number of lines from table during for loop, not multiplied by number of lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of:

```
WHERE keySoPoint AND keyCrdGnssRaw = keyCrdRawMeas
```

I *guess* you meant this:

```
WHERE keySoPoint = keyCrdRawMeas
AND keyCrdGnssRaw = keyCrdRawMeas
```

I'd also recommend that you start using the JOIN syntax as it makes errors in the join conditions less likely:

```
SELECT Name, C1, C2, C3, NumofEpochs, HDop, VDop, NumOfGpsSats, SecondsFrom1970
FROM tblCrdRawMeas 
JOIN tblCrdGnssRaw ON keyCrdGnssRaw = keyCrdRawMeas
JOIN tblSoPoints ON keySoPoint = keyCrdRawMeas
```

This provides a number of benefits including being easier to read and easier to modify to use outer joins should you need that.